# Can I use binding arguments in a copy_to query?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Currently I am using the `copy_to(..)` function to get the following output:

```
   >>> cur.copy_to(sys.stdout, 'test', sep="|")
   1|100|abc'def
   2|\N|dada
   ...
```

What I would like to achieve is to use the `copy_to(..)` function for selecting large amounts of data. I reviewed the documentation for psycopg2, however I could not find a way to use binding arguments with this function. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the `psycopg` docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#copy):

> Reads data from a file-like object appending them to a database table

"What's a file-like object?" you might ask.  [File objects are described in the python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) and the distinction between them and file-like objects are indicated there.  In general, it's an object that supports methods like `open()`/`read()`/`write()`/`close()` with the signatures matching that of the file object.

So the way to bind it would be either to use a real file (consider the [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) module), or an in-memory "file" like that in [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html).